# Issue of jquery validate

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate my form. Why I can't add a field named 'captcha-solution' and validate it? When I added this field,I got js error:

```
missing : after property id
```

captcha-solution: "required",

I am very confused.Can anybody tell my why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an object key with a `-`.

Try this...

```
'captcha-solution': "required",
```

I wrapped the key in quotes.